# Angular 2 / 4 CSS component A affects component B

Tags: css, angular, module, components

[image]

In my app I have 3 components.

**AppComponente** with `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` to route to **Frontend** or **Backend** components.

My problem is that the Frontend.component and Backend.component has diferent CSS's ... but when I RELOAD one of them, something strange happens and the CSS of the other component dont work.

I try to use `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` and Native/Emulated in many combinations but, the problem still happen.

Is a wrong pratice build 2 modules in one application ? Backend and Frontend ?

I'm very confuse now.

Comment: can you create a plunker?"

Comment: I put my project in my Github account, it is an Angular-cli project https://github.com/duard/appSimples